# How to get names from email-adress which includes the names

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a Main-Datatable like this:

| ID | Name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Conner | john.conner@gmail.com |
| 2 | Tyson, Mike | mike.tyson@gmail.com |
| 3 | Harrison Ford | harisson.ford@gmail.com |

The structure of the names are not the same.

My problem and question is, how do I get the name if I only enter the last name?

For example, I get the name "Tyson, Mike" when I type the name "Tyson".
I don't get the name "John Conner" when I type the name Conner.

Is it possible to find the last name entered in the email address in order to display the name from Column "Name"?

The result of the following query shows me all names:

```
SELECT name FROM students WHERE email regexp '(?<=\.).*?(?=@)'
```

The result of the email.Regxp is the last names. How can I compare the regex result with the name "Conner"?

Comment: "when I type the name Conner" - what does that mean? Where do you type anything?

Comment: With an input dialog. The Input is the name maybe Conner and i want the Result John Conner. Doesn't work. It works with tyson, because the Name begins with "Tyson, ...".

Comment: MySQL does not know anything about "input dialogs". If this is part of your application, please share the query that it uses

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the last name would always be just a single word (not always true, e.g. `Jean-Claude Van Damme`, we can try the following approach, e.g. for `Tyson`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM students
WHERE Name LIKE '% Tyson' OR Name LIKE 'Tyson,%';
```

The above logic caters to the last name either being the last word in the `Name` field, or the first word in the `Name` field, followed by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE Operator for this.

```
SELECT name FROM students WHERE email LIKE '%email%'
```

hope this will help you.